# Delegating events firing repetion

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates

I was certain I hade this nailed, but I am getting repetion of the action

```
$('body').on('click', "[data-behave='revealEditNote']", function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    $(e.target).closest('.editPanel').children('.editNote').slideToggle();

});
```

I thought stopPropagation prevented that, but I must be mistaken...

Comment: And what are you trying to achive? Allow closing '.editNote' by clicking anywhere outside of its area? Remember that you bind on events on propagation phase, so the event is handled first by nodes deepest in the DOM and then propagates up to body (in your example). So stopping propagation on body doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: What do you mean by getting a repetition of the action? Is it showing more than one .editNote?

Comment: Perhaps you need `stopImmediatePropagation`? Difficult to be sure without a fiddle...

Comment: It could also depend on when and how you are attaching the handler.  It's possible to attached an event handler twice.

Comment: If you have a `[data-behave='revealEditNote']` inside a `[data-behave='revealEditNote']` guess what...and without markup this is obvious speculation at best.

Comment: Trent, can I test for that before reattaching?